# can't load css file when load local html to webview via react-native@iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I'm using react native, I tried to load local html to webview and debug with iOS simulator, **the html file loaded sucessful**, but **css file** and **js file** are not available, I use safari to debug it, it show these message:

```
[Warning] Viewport argument value "0;" for key "user-scalable" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. (page1.html, line 6)
[Error] Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:8081/assets/web1/page1.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
[Error] Refused to execute http://localhost:8081/assets/web1/page1.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

this is my rn code

```
  render() {
    const PolicyHTML = require('XXUxLab/web1/page1.html');
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          // source={{uri: this.state.webPageUrl2}}
          source={PolicyHTML}
          style={styles.Web_view}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          useWebKit={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

this is how html ref css file

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page1.css">
```

web1 folder is in the root of react native project,  page1.html, page1.html and page1.js in the web1 folder.

I tried to host the webpage files to a server, and load the web page with url in rn code, it worked. But why it can't work in local ? I real want to know the root cause, I guess maybe the issue was caused by Metro service config.